Branched covering maps between Riemann surfaces
What is an example of a branched covering map between Riemann surfaces of infinite degree? i.e. something like a branched version of the exponential map $exp: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^*$.
Thanks!

Obviously infinite-sheeted branched covers only exist in the noncompact setting.  For examples, just take the (unbranched) universal cover of a compact surface of positive genus.

Thanks But I am looking for a branched (not unbranched) cover ;)

Then lift a branched cover between compact Riemann surfaces to their universal covers.

For instance, the $j$-function mapping the upper half-plane onto the complex plane.

For infinite degree, the definition of "branched covering" can be somewhat ambiguous. But
$$z\mapsto \cos z: \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$$
$$\wp: \mathbb{C}\to S$$ are a simple examples of  branched coverings, according to any definition. Here $S$ is the Riemann sphere. They are regular (factors by some groups). Here is an example of non-regular one:
$$z\mapsto ze^z: \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}.$$
